# Utilizar ON CASCADE DELETE em SQL

Tags: sql

Eu tenho duas tabelas em SQL, uma chamada Doente e outra Diagnostico, consigo fazer todas as operações com o diagnostico(inserir,editar e apagar), mas eu apenas gostaria que fosse possível apagar os diagnósticos que não estivessem associados a um doente.

PRIMEIRA PERGUNTA: terei de criar uma foreign key para diagnostico na tabela doente?

SEGUNDA PERGUNTA: como devo utilizar o ON CASCADE DELETE para garantir que o diagnóstico  não seja apagado caso um doente já tenha esse diagnostico?

MINHAS TABELAS NO SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Doente] (
    [Id]             INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [numero]         INT            NOT NULL,
    [nome]           NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [sexo]           NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [dataNascimento] DATE           NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Diagnostico] (
    [Id]        INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [descricao] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Quais as relações entre Diagnóstico e Doente? Um doente pode ter mais de um diagnóstico ou é um diagnóstico que pode ter mais de um doente?

Comment: O objetivo é que um doente possa ter vários diagnósticos e que um diagnóstico também possa estar associado a vários doentes...uma relação de N...N

Comment: Se você adicionar o comando On Cascade Delete na criação da tabela, sempre que você deletar na tabela Pai, será deletado na(s) tabela(s) filha(s). Isso tem um custo, talvez não tão caro, mas tem. Quanto a sua condição, você poderá criar uma SP para fazer essa verificação e depois deletar. Acho que é isso.

Comment: http://magaweb.com.br/blog/incluindo-o-comando-on-delete-cascade-em-uma-tabela/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se quer que exista uma relação *Many-to-Many* entre ***Diagnostico*** e ***Doente*** é necessário definir uma outra tabela para representar essa relação.

Essa tabela deverá ter 2 campos um para guardar o ID do diagnóstico e outro o ID do doente.

Ambos deverão ser *foreign key* para garantir que não se possa eliminar um doente que tenha diagnóstico ou um diagnóstico que tenha um doente.

O *ON CASCADE DELETE* não se aplica ao que você pretende.

Answer (score 1):

> Eu tenho duas tabelas em SQL, uma chamada Doente e outra Diagnostico,
>   consigo fazer todas as operações com o diagnostico(inserir,editar e
>   apagar), mas eu apenas gostaria que fosse possível apagar os
>   diagnósticos que não estivessem associados a um doente.
>
> PRIMEIRA PERGUNTA: terei de criar uma foreign key para diagnostico na
>   tabela doente?

Sim, em uma relação 1-to-1, nos outros casos leia o ramaral.

> SEGUNDA PERGUNTA: como devo utilizar o ON CASCADE DELETE para garantir
>   que o diagnóstico não seja apagado caso um doente já tenha esse
>   diagnostico?

Jamais, primeiro que esse comando não funciona mais no MSSQL Server, segundo que ele foi criado com o intuito oposto, ou seja, ele "burla" as constraints apagando as dependências primeiro.